# Password Change with the Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

Is there a way to change your twitter password via the python-twitter API or the twitter API in general? I have looked around but can't seem to find this information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately **not**!  Passwords are very confidential information which only Twitter itself wants to handle.

---

Think about a third-party developer suggesting to change your Twitter password:

- would you trust them and let them see your new password?
- how could you make sure they are really going to set your new password and not another one?

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib.request
import time

def set_password():
password="PASSWORDHERE"

set_password()

def send_to_twitter(msg):
password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr()
password_manager.add_password("Twitter API",
           "http://twitter.com/statuses", "twitterhandlehere",password)
http_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
page_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(http_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(page_opener)
params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {'status': msg} )
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json",    params)
resp.read()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.